# Stepping through Javascript in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to step through a javascript function but Visual studio doesnt allow me to go inside the function.

```
 function foo() {
  var x = 5; // have put a breakpoint
  var y = 10;
  var t = x + y;
  alert('Hello');
 }
```

I am using Internet Explorer where in Advanced settings, I have unchecked the Disable Script Debugging.

When I run the code, I see the popup showing Hello (which means its going inside the function). It doesn't allow me to step though the code.

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome's developer tools to step through the code.

You can place a `debugger;` line in your code and it will stop at that point.

See more here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Sorry but ain't working. It still skips even though I have debugger; line added. Just shows me the hello popup

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome and do you have the developer tools open? (Options -> More Tools -> Developer Tools).

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireFox with FireBug installed http://getfirebug.com/. Make sure when running your project through FireFox that you have FireBug activated and place a debugger; in your function. It should hit that debugger and allow you to step through your javascript.